# actionscript determine user environment

Tags: flash, actionscript, user-environment

is it possible using actionscript to determine what operating system the flash projector is running on...I'm producing a swf that is to run from a cd-rom and so will be published as an .exe for windows and a .app for mac...parts of the presentation change depending on what os the user is running it on...i don't want to have to publish, change things and then republish...

if it were a swf embedded on a web page, the browser would provide all those details...

**edit**
in actionscript 2? thanks branden for the as3 suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works with projectors, but check out flash.system.Capabilities - there's a property in there called os that *should* have what you need.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html